# How to change URL for SharePoint:SiteLogoImage

Tags: site-definition

I have the job of migrating a sharepoint site from one server to another.

Everything appears to have moved across correctly, but there is one image which has a url to the old site.

I've tried editing the master page, but there seems to only be placeholders.

The image appears to be part of the site definition or template.

Where should I look to change the image source for this image?

Update:

I found the following in default.master.

```
<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage id="onetidHeadbnnr0" 
LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/titlegraphic.gif" runat="server"/>
```

But it seems to be getting the image source from somewhere else. So where exactly is the URL defined?

Thanks

Comment: This is so silly. What is the use of all these properties if they do nothing or something completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell which image you are referring but most likey it is a URL that should have been specified by the user and not part of site definition.

If you are referring to site's logo image, it may have been specified in the "Title, description and icon" page under site settings. that would browse you to _layouts/prjsetng.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to change this via css/javascript on the masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but the `SiteLogoImage` control's `LogoImageUrl` property uses the value specified in markup as a fallback only when the [`SPWeb.SiteLogoUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitelogourl.aspx) property is set to an empty string. Otherwise, the value specified for each web is used. This is to allow customization of this control's display for each web.

Usually I'll specify this value in an event receiver for a branding feature (and revert it on removal of the branding in the `FeatureDeactivating` event), but you could also manipulate it via PowerShell.

This is the underlying value set in the "Title, description and icon" page Ashish is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just replacing it with a `<a><img></img></a>` routine.

Wonder where on earth you really change that value.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to comment on this, but you can change the image url from:

> Site Actions > Site Settings > Title, description and icon(under Look
>   and Feel) > Logo Url and description